# Can I make a laptop access the Internet via another laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I have a laptop with a nonworking internal wifi adapter, and [a sometimes not working external wifi adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546195/network-manager-goes-bad-after-hot-unplugging-an-external-usb-wifi-adapter) (the problem can be solved by restarting its Lubuntu). I can access another laptop which has a working internal wifi adapter.

When the external wifi adapter is not working with the first laptop, and I don't want to restart its Lubuntu, can I use the second laptop to allow the first laptop to access the Internet? What shall I do both both hardware and software wise?

Thanks.

Comment: Do both laptops have an RJ-45 ethernet port?  If so you can cable them to each other and share the internet from laptop 2 to laptop 1.  I imagine the steps for you will be similar to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

Comment: As long as the machine you want to use as a router has sufficient connectivity (I'm guessing one wireless and one wired NIC), then no problem - just set it up like any other router.  It doesn't matter whether it's a laptop, a RPi, or any other form-factor.