# How can I kill a stubborn process?

Tags: process, networkmanager

I have a NetworkManager process (in status `R`) consuming   85% CPU, and am not certain why but [it happens sometimes after I hot unplug an external wifi adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546195/network-manager-goes-bad-after-hot-unplugging-an-external-usb-wifi-adapter).

Trying to kill it by `sudo kill 1068`, `sudo service NetworkManager restart/stop` or `sudo systemctl restart/stop NetworkManager` will result in hanging forever.

Also it seems any `sudo` command hangs forever.

Is there a way to kill the process?

Comment: Did you try kill -9?

Comment: Yes, with `sudo`

Comment: `kill -9` or `pkill` has always worked for me when a process has a stubborn refusal to expire. If that's not working for you and it's hanging then I don't know what to say.

Comment: I am not saying this is definitely your case, but, when a process refuses to die with kill or kill -9, it means it is waiting for an event, mostly hardware related. By hot unplugging the wifi adapter, probably you are preventing this event from taking place. It might be waiting for a signal from the adapter, before it can clear out all necessary values, to prevent a future conflict, which never comes. Hence the hung process. Your wifi adapter/driver may not be as hot-pluggable as you may think. Just a suggestion.

Comment: `sudo kill -KILL 1068` would be an alternative, complete command. Is it not a sudo problem? As Nasir says 9=SIGKILL always works (on a running process).

Comment: @MelBurslan if my wifi adpater is not hot unpluggable, how shall I unplug it?

Comment: Since I have never tried doing anything like this, what I am telling is an educated guess, but there has to be a way to stop the adapter from the linux interface, let it be GUI or shell. (`ifcfg wlan0 down` command comes to mind, wlan0 as an example YMMV) You can do that and then unload the kernel module (which is basically the driver) with the `modprobe -r` command. Then you should be able to remove the adapter. I know it is not very user friendly but as you know UNIX is selective about its friends :)